# How to use chart control to show charts on web page?

Tags: asp.net

I have a downloaded Microsoft chart control. I am not able to use it.

I have a web application in which there are number of online question & have 3 option Yes, No, Unsure. User can visit to the site, maybe go to solve the question.

I want to display the web chart that display the chart which shows number of Yes, No, Cancel as per question against any number vote.

Please give me reply how to use chart control for this. I am completely unaware with it.

Regards,
Rishi

Comment: No need for the multiple question marks. Stay calm.

Comment: Have you seen http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart? Or http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx?

Comment: What multiple question marks.  :) See, calmer already.

This screams out for a quick MSDN search to get a nice example for how to use the control. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Nope, I don't think you're missing anything. Some people don't seem to know about basic resources like this. Someday I hope to know, not only _why_ they don't know, but also _how_.

Comment: John, I would focus on doing what you do best. You many not want to know why or how in these cases. You might be quite better off.

Comment: What I do best is fix problems. I'd like to know, so that I can at least _try_ to fix the problem of people not knowing about resources.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you should add data to `Chart1.Series[0].Points`.

Have a look at the [official site](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart), it has samples, and you can download a project with many samples: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1591

Here's code from the official sample to create a pie chart (most of it is optional):

```
// Populate series data
double[]    yValues = {65.62, 75.54, 60.45, 34.73, 85.42};
string[]    xValues = {"France", "Canada", "Germany", "USA", "Italy"};
Chart1.Series["Default"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);

// Set Doughnut chart type
Chart1.Series["Default"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Doughnut;

// Set labels style
Chart1.Series["Default"]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";

// Set Doughnut radius percentage
Chart1.Series["Default"]["DoughnutRadius"] = "30";

// Explode data point with label "Italy"
Chart1.Series["Default"].Points[4]["Exploded"] = "true";

// Enable 3D
Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enabled = true; 

// Disable the Legend
Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Kobis answer will be a good start. Also you can use Google charts API. Google charts will just need you to create a URL & it returns an image. But may be it may not be as configurable as Microsoft chart control.

Link: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/